# I am trying to use use this validation in my html tag by using onsubmit=return validateForm()

Tags: javascript, jsp

```
//this is the javascript program for validation

function validateForm()
    {  
        var name=document.myform.uname.value;  
        var password=document.myform.password.value; 
        var conpass = document.myform.repassword.value;
        boolean valid = true;
    if(password != conpass)
    {
         alert("password is not same");
         valid=false;
    }

    else if(name==null || name=="") 
    {
        alert("User Name should not be blank.."); 
        valid=false; 
    } 
    else if(password==""|| password==null)
    { 
        alert("Password should not be blank"); 
        valid=false;
        }
    else if(!this.form.checkbox.checked)
    {
        alert('You must agree to the terms first.');
        return false;
    }
    else{

        return valid;
    }

    };
```

//and this is the html in which I am using this but it is not working properly,it is not taking the js validation and directly forwarding me to the reg.jsp page.

```
<form action="reg.jsp"  name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
```

Comment: onsubmit="return validateForm()"  this should be onsubmit=" validateForm()"

Comment: it is still not working.

Comment: add you html to the question. It will be easier to test.

Comment: `boolean valid = true;` is not javascript

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent submit via javascript, you have to return `false` in your onsubmit handler.

So the in the following line the `validateForm()` must return false:

```
<form action="reg.jsp"  name="myform" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" >
```

You have many if-else blocks that set the `var valid = false` and this is ok.
But this `valid` variable should be returned. You do this only in the last `else` blocks.

```
else if(!this.form.checkbox.checked)
{
    alert('You must agree to the terms first.');
    return false;
}
else{

    return valid;
}
```

The previous checks are just preparing the variable, but don't return it.
And this is what you need to do.

Here is an example how it can be done:

```
function validateForm() {  
    var name=document.myform.uname.value;  
    var password=document.myform.password.value; 
    var conpass = document.myform.repassword.value;

    var valid = true;
    var message = "everything is valid";

    if(password != conpass)
    {
        message = "password is not same";
        valid = false;
    }
    else if(name==null || name=="") 
    {
        message = "User Name should not be blank.."; 
        valid = false; 
    } 
    else if(password==""|| password==null)
    { 
        message = "Password should not be blank"; 
        valid = false;
    }
    else if(!this.form.checkbox.checked)
    {
        message = "You must agree to the terms first.";
        valid = false;
    }

    alert(message);    
    return valid;    
};
```

Other improvement could be:

- Reordering the conditions by descending importance.
  For example: if the Term are not accepted, is not important, if the password is empty.
  If password is empty, it is not important, if the conpass is the same.
- Using html5, which hast more input types and adjustable build-in validation for common cases. See more here: http://html5doctor.com/html5-forms-input-types/